# A family of dynamical systems similar to Conway's Game Of Life

Tags: pr.probability, discrete-dynamical-systems

Given a dimension $d\geq 1$ and two subsets $\mathcal B$ (the 'birth' set)
and $\mathcal D$ (the 'death' set) of $\lbrace 0,\ldots,2d\rbrace$, we consider the
dynamical system $\lbrace \mu_0,\mu_1\rbrace$ on states $\sigma\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace^{\mathbb Z^d}$
with $\mu_\epsilon$ defined as follows:
$\mu_\epsilon(\sigma(x_1,\ldots,x_d))=\sigma(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ if $\sum x_i\not \equiv \epsilon
\pmod 2$.

If $\sum x_i\equiv \epsilon\pmod 2$ and $\sigma(\mathbf x)=0$ then
$\mu_\epsilon$ changes the value of the state at $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$
(i.e. $\mu_{\epsilon}(\sigma(\mathbf x))=1$ if and only if $\sum_{\mathbf y\in\mathcal N(\mathbf x)}\sigma(\mathbf y)\in\mathcal B$
where $\mathcal N(\mathbf x)=\lbrace (y_1,\ldots,y_d),\sum\vert x_i-y_i\vert=1\rbrace$ is the set of all $2d$ immediate neighbours at Euclidean distance $1$
of $\mathbf x$.

If $\sum x_i\equiv \epsilon\pmod 2$ and $\sigma(\mathbf x)=1$ then
$\mu_\epsilon$ changes the value of the state at $\mathbf x$
(i.e. $\mu_{\epsilon}(\sigma(\mathbf x))=0$) if and only if $\sum_{\mathbf y\in\mathcal N(\mathbf x)}\sigma(\mathbf y)\in\mathcal D$.

In plain words, $\mu_\epsilon$ induces only changes at sites with
coordinate-sum
$\epsilon\pmod 2$. If $\mathbf x$ is such a site which is not living
(i.e. $\sigma(\mathbf x)=0$) then $\mu_\epsilon$ induces a living site at
$\mathbf x$ if and only if the number of living neighbours of $\mathbf x$
belongs to the birth-set $\mathcal B$. Similarly, a living site $\mathbf x$
(with coordinate-sum $\epsilon$ modulo $2$) dies if the number of
its living neighbours belongs to the death-set $\mathcal D$.

Starting from an initial state
$\sigma_0:\mathbb Z^d\longmapsto \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$
we set $\sigma_{2n+1}=\mu_0(\sigma_{2n})$
and $\sigma_{2n}=\mu_1(\sigma_{2n-1})$. (For simulations, I worked
with an initial state $\sigma_0$ which is $N\mathbb Z^2$-periodic for some
large even integer $N$.)

The number of all $4^{2d+1}$ such systems can be reduced by a factor of
$2$ by observing that $(\mathcal D'=\overline{\mathcal B},
\mathcal B'=\overline{\mathcal D})$ is equivalent to $(\mathcal B,\mathcal D)$,
up to replacing
$\sigma$ by $1-\sigma$ where $\overline{\mathcal X}=\lbrace x,\ 2d-x\not\in\mathcal X\rbrace
\subset \lbrace 0,\ldots,2d\rbrace$.

Systems associated to non-intersecting sets $\mathcal B,\mathcal D$ are
particularly interesting: $\mathcal B\cap \mathcal D=\{\}$
amounts to idempotency $\mu_\epsilon\circ\mu_\epsilon=\mu_\epsilon$
of the two maps $\mu_0,\mu_1$.

We restrict now our attention further to the $2^{2d+1}$ cases
where $\mathcal B,\mathcal D$ form a partition of $\lbrace
0,\ldots,2d\rbrace$:
We have therefore $\mathcal B\cap\mathcal D=\lbrace \rbrace$ and
$\mathcal B\cup\mathcal D=\lbrace 0,\ldots,2d\rbrace$.

For $d=2$, there are 32 such systems, completely described by the subset
$\mathcal B$ of $\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$. Using equivalence (up to exchanging
$\sigma$ with $1-\sigma$) of such a system,
we can assume that $\mathcal B$ has at most two elements.

Starting with a random state $\sigma_0$ (obtained, say, by coin-tosses)
8 of the 16 systems (with $\mathcal B$ containing at most two elements
in $\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$) seem perhaps
to have non-trivial typical limit-probabilities $p_\infty(\mathcal B)$
for living sites. The corresponding
sets $\mathcal B$ and approximate values of $p_\infty(\mathcal B)$
are given by:
$$\begin{array}{cll}
    \mathcal B&p_\infty(\mathcal B)&p_i\\
    \hline
    \lbrace 1\rbrace&.34&.3700\\
    \lbrace 0,2\rbrace&.46&.4566\\
    \lbrace 1,2\rbrace&.51&.5579\\
    \lbrace 0,3\rbrace&.34&.3093\\
    \lbrace 1,3\rbrace&.50&1/ 2\\
    \lbrace 2,3\rbrace&.63&.2373,.6846\\
    \lbrace 0,4\rbrace&.36&.2779\\
    \lbrace 1,4\rbrace&.37&.3820\\
\end{array}$$
where the last row gives the expected probability
$$p_i=\sum_{b\in\mathcal B}{4\choose b}p_i^b(1-p_i)^{4-b}$$
assuming (erroneously!) independency of the state at different sites.
The case $\mathcal B=\lbrace 2,3\rbrace$ leads to
two possible values $p_i$ in $(0,1)$, assuming independency.
Simulations seem to indicate the possible existence of a
typical limit-probability $p_\infty$ close to the larger root.

*Can one prove the existence of typical limit-probabilities
$p_\infty(\mathcal B)$ in some of these eight cases and can they
be computed exactly?*

A few remarks: The system on $\mathbb Z^d$ associated to
the set $\mathcal B=\lbrace 1,3,5,\ldots,2d-1\rbrace$ of all $d$ odd integers
is particularly symmetric: Does its limit-density $p_\infty$
exist and is it exactly equal to $1/2$? (This seems also to hold
in dimension $d=1$ where it is obvious that typical states are very far
from independent coin-tosses: There are never more than three consecutive $1$'s
in $\sigma_n$ for $n\geq 2$.)